# what does "oi lad!" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, expressions

There was this moment in some guy's video where a warrior swings a sword at some other guy. Then the other guy says "oi lad!" parrying the sword. What does that mean? why would he say that.

Comment: 'Oi' is used in sense of 'Hey' and 'lad' means 'a man' . So it means - Hey Man!

Comment: isn't hey like hello, or look at me!, listen! something like that? I don't get the actual nuance

Comment: [define oi](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+oi) |  [define lad](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+lad)

Comment: Suppose you were walking down the street one day, minding your own business, and someone comes up to you and punches you on your arm for no reason. If your response was a single word, what word would it be?

Comment: @Lawrence A single word? 'Ow'

Comment: @Mitch *Oi*! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**oi**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Oi)
interj.  British Slang

> Used as a greeting or to attract someone's attention.

As in:  [google books: *Dreams of the Sou*l](https://books.google.com/books?id=pQRcAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA431&dq=oi%20lad&pg=PA431#v=onepage&q=oi%20lad&f=false)

> Oi, oi lad, shut your pie hole and stop chirping... Oi, lad! It is
>   over, over!